# Bash snippet to see if something is listening on a port?

Tags: networking, bash, scripting, snippet

I want to see if something is listening on a port on localhost. I was going to use `nc` and check the exit code.

Something like this:

```
echo "" | nc localhost 14881
echo $?
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: there are many reasons why you'd want to do this, but I'm curious as to your reason here... it may be possible you can avoid the port-check altogether.  Do you have a 'slow start' scenario?  where the application daemonizes but takes another minute or two before it actually opens up a listener?  or are you just trying to avoid a lengthy timeout situation?  or are you unable to handle the case where you get connection refused?

Comment: with nc correct way will be  nc -z "$host" "$port", in bash though the proper way would be  echo '123' > /dev/tcp/localhost/port" and if there is nothing listens it will says: "bash: connect: Connection refused"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

lsof -i :14881

Comment: This one provides lots of great data.

Comment: On my desktop system this one requires root.

Comment: `lsof -i :14881 | grep ":14881"` then you can use `echo $?`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe netstat would be better because the port might not be listening on localhost or it might be blocked by iptables:

```
netstat -ln  | grep :14881
echo $?
```

Grep will exit with 1 if there is no match.  If you want just tcp and/or udp , add the -u or -t switches to netstat.

Answer (score 2):

If you are root:

```
netstat -lnp | grep ':14881 '
```

Comment: Just to be clear: it will still work if you aren't root but you won't benefit from seeing the process name bound to it.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in bash for exiting when no-one listening to this port.

```
$port="14881"
if [[ $(netstat -ltn | grep ":${port} " | wc -l) -eq "0" ]] ; then echo "Port $port not listened to" && exit 1; fi
```

- Using bash double brackets and comparing against wc for easy reading..

Comment: Passing the "-c" argument to grep obviates the need for "wc -l"

Answer (score 0):

netstat -ano | egrep LISTEN | egrep tcp | egrep $PORTNUMBER

Comment: Woah, lay off the pipes. You can replace the first two egreps with `-lt` instead of `-ao` and a normal grep on the port. Or, if you wished, perform everything as a single egrep.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ss -lntup` will tell you what is listening for TCP/UDP connections - you can filter the output as might be suitable (e.g. listening on 127.0.0.1, ::1, 0.0.0.0).

If you have python around, you can also create a dumb portscanner (only really worthwhile for TCP, though):

```
import socket

for p in range(1,2**16):
   try:
     s = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1',p))
     print "Listener on tcp/{}".format(p)
   except:
     continue
```